# Como direcciono un dominio al contenido de otra website?

Tags: web, redirección, dominio

quisiera saber como hago para direccionar un dominio a otra website. 
Es decir:
www.exemplo1.com --> fue creada hace 2 anos y ahora le cambiaran el nombre por:
www.exemplo123.com --> Este dominio ha sido comprado, porque le cambiaron el nombre, sin embargo cuando hagan coloquen el dominio en internet, debe ser redireccionado a la web: www.exemplo1.com, ya que esta el sitio web está ahi. Mi pregunta es muy basica, espero que me puedan ayudar.

Gracias!

Comment: Si el dominio que quieres redireccionar es de tu propiedad o tienes acceso al panel de gestión del mismo, suele existir la opción de configurarlo como redirección. Es lo más rápido. Mira las opciones de tu proveedor de dominios o pregunta a soporte técnico.

Comment: Si, claro si tengo el acceso, ya que es el dominio anterior del nuevo. Me parece que es un web forward? Lo estoy revisando, igual revisare con soporte tecnico. Gracias :)